# 13.10, second monitor: how do I make the "Display: HDMI1" box go away?

Tags: 13.10, display, xfce

I've got a new laptop on which I've installed 13.10 and I use XFCE as my desktop. I want to use the laptop with an external monitor, and that works fine, mostly. However, when I use the "Display" settings control to select the screen to use, the blue box that shows up to tell me that my external monitor is "HDMI1" does not go away after I've set things up. Here's what it looks like:
[image: screenshot]

It won't go away. I've dismissed the "Display" settings application, but the thing is still there. What is going on?

Overall the XFCE display chooser seems to work much, much worse in 13.10 than in 13.04. It's a crapshoot whether it can re-enable the laptop display or not. I can do it reliably with `xrandr`, so I don't think it's a low-level problem.

*edit* If I turn the external monitor off with `xrandr` and then back on, the stupid thing comes back.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I found it. A zombie-like stray copy of `xfce4-display-settings` was stuck somehow. I found it (via `ps axf`) and killed it, and the thing went away.